# Access denied to the bucket ******

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, vmime

I am new to AWS and i am trying to export VM images from AWS EC2 to S3 bucket that I had already imported using VMImport/Export service . I tried to export using AWS CLI and SDK (python) as well , but both returns the same error :

**An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the ExportImage operation: Access denied to the bucket ******23**
Entered parameters are correct and i have given all public access to the S3 bucket used in Export action. Still the error continues to appear.
Any help would be greatly appreciated 
Thanks in advance

Comment: refer https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/ to troubleshoot

Comment: I tried trouble shooting,  S3 access works fine for multi part upload , VM import  except  for Export service  despite using the same IAM role for all the services

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you have given public access to the Amazon S3 bucket, and the commands you are using that generates the error.

Comment: This is the command i used to export image (the command that generates error)                                                  
 aws ec2 export-image --image-id ami-*********** --disk-image-format RAW --s3-export-location S3Bucket=*******  --role-name vmimport1                                     In S3 bucket permissions I had  turned on all public access and also granted read write permissions  for  canonical ID of the account

Comment: Also getting this...

Comment: Similar issue resolved ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73072539/an-error-occurred-invalidparameter-when-calling-the-createinstanceexporttask-o/73072578#73072578

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same issue , make sure the open the bucket and again give permission write read in S3 bucket as attached in image

Step 1[Open your bucket s3 in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDLk7.jpg)

step 2[Go to permission tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQasU.jpg)

Step 3[Make it public and ACL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUnQ8.jpg)

Step 4[Give the read write permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWyfx.jpg)

But best practice make IAM and add that account to permissions