# An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the CreateInstanceExportTask operation: Access denied to the bucket xxxx

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

While performing ec2 vm export to s3 getting error access denied to bucket

command used:

```
aws ec2 create-instance-export-task --description "my vm instance" --instance-id i-abcdefgh --target-environment vmware --export-to-s3-task DiskImageFormat=vmdk,ContainerFormat=ova,S3Bucket=store-vms,S3Prefix=vms
```

OR

```
aws ec2 create-instance-export-task --instance-id i-abcdefgh --target-environment vmware --export-to-s3-task file://file.json
```

content of file.json

```
{
    "ContainerFormat": "ova",
    "DiskImageFormat": "VMDK",
    "S3Bucket": "store-vms",
    "S3Prefix": "vms/"
}
```

aws cli is connected correctly, it can list buckets and also put file to s3

Answer (score 1):

Resolved:

added Grantee, Region-specific canonical account ID to S3 ACL with read/write permission

Navigate to: Amazon S3 -> Buckets -> yourbucketname -> permissions -> Access control list (ACL) -> Edit

Find section named:  Access for other AWS accounts, add relevant canonical account ID and permissions

After adding canonical account ID:
[image]

Find relevent grantee by ref:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmexport.html